# Javascript random number generator with function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

alright, so I have an assignment here where I need to generate a random number but its not working so well. I've done it before but things aren't working for me; basically even tho we are generating rnadom numbers it needs to show the user to go up or down if the guess isn't correct and at least one random time the nuber the user guesses is supposed to be correct. Apparently i have things misplaced but my coding is right. I'm trying to figure out how to get this working and an explanation why i was wrong because i'm still learning a lot. Thank you.

```
<html>
```

Number guessing game
    
  
  
    Welcome to number guessing game. Please make a guess between 1 and 10 to find the hidden number
    
    Make a guess
    
    
      // 1. Generate a number between 1 and 10 - done
      // 2. Create a function named guess so that when button is clicked function is executed. - done
      // 2.1. Inside the function get the value user entered from the input box. - done
      // 2.2. Inside the function check if the number is smaller than randomNumber, if so display "Go up" in the div with result id. - done
      // 2.3. Inside the function check if the number is bigger than randomNumber, if so display "Go down" in the div with result id. - done
      // 2.4. Inside the function check if the number is equal to randomNumber, if so display "You guessed right!" in the div with result id. - done

```
  //If working correctly your page should allow the player to guess the correct number by getting instructions from your code.
                 function guess() {

                    var userInput = parseInt($("#guess").val());
                    console.log(userInput);
                    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
                    console.log(randomNumber);



                if (randomNumber == userInput) {

            $("#result").html(`you guess correctly!`);
            console.log(result);
        } else if (randomNumber < userInput) {
            $("#result").html(`higher!`);
        } else {
            $("#result").html(`lower!`);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Your code is missing a `#` in `$("result")`

Comment: The "secret number" is going to change every time the user guesses. So they're basically never going to win.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it's the _Dark Souls_ of number guessing games

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol THAT'S WHAT MAKES IT FUN

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  thank you so much, . basically i'm supposed to  be able to tell the user to go up or down and they supposed to be able to generate a number and win at least once randomly.

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath haha thank you for that i'm still new and i literally miss out on the smallest things

Comment: if anyone knows how to make this a runnable example please let me know as i'm still learning how to use this site lol

Comment: A couple of people are already giving you some hints but let me spell it out - **don't generate the random number inside `guess()`**. Generate it **ONE TIME** outside `guess()` and store it in a global variable. This is not a javascript bug but more of a math/logic bug

Comment: @slebetman -ok so i tried putting it outside and its still giving me the wrong value. for example; if the user inputs 2 and the random number is 6 it'll output "go lower!" and thats it..